# Saving and reading data from excel file(C# WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, excel

I have to make a simple WPF application that manages and displays some data in form of objects(strings and ints). It needs to be saved in excel format, so that it can me manually opened and viewed by any user with Excel. But because not every user necessarily has Excel it needs to be independent from it. I found very few solutions but none worked for me. [This](https://support.microsoft.com/sl-si/kb/302084) works but as far as I know it needs Excel installed to run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel without having Microsoft Office installed.

You can use external libraries that allow xls or xlsx modification without Excel installed:

- http://code.google.com/p/excellibrary/
- http://simpleooxml.codeplex.com/ (only xlsx)

Comment: Thanks! I was googling for hours and somehow didn't find any library for my needs...

Answer (score 2):

I use EPPlus for this purpose. http://epplus.codeplex.com/

It does not require that you have excel installed and is easy to use.

Comment: Thanks! I was googling for hours and somehow didn't find any library for my needs...

Comment: I've used this a lot. It's really nice. The only drawback is that it only supports xlsx, not xls.

Comment: Can xlsx be opened in any version of Excel?

Comment: No, but all versions from 2007 and up can, so almost everybody can use them.